# Volume of a solid with Triple Integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral

I need to find the volume of the following solid Q using triple integral

[image]

I am confuse, what are the limits of integration? please give me some hint

Comment: Here's a hint. Try to find the limits of integration in the order of $dxdzdy$

Answer (score 2):

We can proceed for example by slices orthogonal to $y$ axis obtaining this set up

$$V=\int_1^3 dy \int_{\frac {y^2} 4}^4dz\int_0^{\sqrt{4z-y^2}} dx$$

or as an alternative

$$V=\int_1^3 dy \int_0^{\sqrt{16-y^2}}dx\int_{\frac{x^2+y^2}4}^{4} dz$$